# How to import files with texture in Blender?

Tags: blender

I downloaded a Blender model from Google and it came with two folders: a "source" folder where is located the .blend file and a "textures" folder with all the image textures.

[image: Folder Image]

Whenever I open the .blend file, only the model shows without the textures. How would I be able to open the file with all the textures already implemented?

Answer (score 0):

You can ask blender to look for the files it's missing by going to: `Info > File > External Data > Find Missing Files`. It will ask you to select the folder you want to be searched.

For more information you can look at this answer on the blender stackexchange: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/5372/35312

You could also try to put the texture folder inside the source folder, and if that doesn't work to put the texture files and the blend file in the same folder.

Comment: Yeah, I already tried to put them in the same folder. Anyway, I'll try the other things out and let you know.